# img tag without ‘src’ attribute in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a img tag in IE9, like `<img id="xxx" />`, without "src" attribute . I use js to set its  "src", and then use `removeAttr` function in Jquery to remove the "src" attribute, but here comes the problem.

[image]

Notice the picture box, there is no "src" attribute, but the page still show the error image.
How to remove it ?

Comment: You could use a spacer image. Which means a small image that is transparent and has the size of 1x1 which will not be noticed and keeps you from showing the error message

Comment: Maybe you can toggle visibility when you add and remove `src` attribute?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by abusing this poor image? It can certainly be done in a more conventional manner, which will present fewer problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it `display:none` with css. For example `$('#that_image').addClass('hidden');` where css is `.hidden {display: none;}`

Answer (score 6):

Either do a show hide as mentioned, or simply define the img as `<img id="xxx" src="" />` and have css:

```
img[src=""] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it when setting and removing the image src. You can also directly change the CSS display attribute with `.css('display', 'none')`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) it from the dom:

```
$('#xxx').remove();
```